# Removing rows based on the combined value of other rows

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, if-statement

I want to remove the row with "SubAggregate"='All' if the rows with the same "Month" and "MainAggregate" sums ("ValueTraded") to the same as the corresponding "SubAggregate"='All' value

My idea was to group by "MainAggregate" and "Month" and if the value was equal to two times the value in the row with an 'All', then it would be deleted. I only got to the point where I grouped the data

```
Tester = data.groupby(["Month", "MainAggregate"], as_index=False)["ValueTraded"].sum()
Tester["ValueTraded"] = Tester["ValueTraded"] / 2
```

Below is an example of the data and the desired output:

- DATA
  [image: Data]
- Desired Output
  [image: Desired Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare `sum` per groups in new columns in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with first `All` value by [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and because duplicates remove only first duplicated value by add [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
mask = df['subaAggregate'].eq('All')

s = df.groupby(["Month", "MainAggregate"])["valueTrad"].transform('sum').div(2)


s1 = (df.assign(new = df['valueTrad'].where(mask))
        .groupby(["Month", "MainAggregate"])["new"].transform('first'))

out = df[s.ne(s1) | ~mask | df.duplicated(['Month','MainAggregate','subaAggregate'])]
```

Or compare filtred rows with only `All` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for indices for remove from original `DataFrame`:

```
#necessary unique indices
#df = df.reset_index(drop=True)    
mask = df['subaAggregate'].eq('All')

s = df.groupby(["Month", "MainAggregate"])["valueTrad"].sum().div(2).rename('new')
df1 = df[mask].drop_duplicates().join(s, on=['Month','MainAggregate'])

out = df.drop(df1.index[df1['valueTrad'].eq(df1['new'])])
```